# SerialPort has no module called 'pause'

Tags: node.js

I downloaded NodeJS SerialPort module from https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport

Below is the way I have used it:

```
var Serialport = require("serialport").SerialPort;
var serialPort = new Serialport("COM1", {
baudrate: 9600,  dataBits: 8,  parity: 'none',  stopBits: 1, flowControl: false, xon : false, rtscts:false, xoff:false, xany:false, bufferSize:0, rtscts: false, dsrdtr: false
});

serialPort.on("open", function () {
console.log('Serial communication open');
serialPort.write("AT+CMGF=1");
serialPort.write('\r');
serialPort.flush();
serialPort.pause ();
serialPort.on('data', function(data) { 
        global.recData += data.toString()
        if (global.recData.indexOf("OK") >= 0)                
          serialPort.resume();
        });
});
```

But I get an error -

```
            serialPort.pause ();
                       ^
TypeError: Object #<SerialPort> has no method 'pause'
    at SerialPort.<anonymous> (E:\NodeJS\bas\routes\serial.js:40:24)
    at SerialPort.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at E:\NodeJS\node_modules\serialport\serialport.js:201:12
```

As per the document it has 'pause' and 'resume' methods? Why am I getting this error - if method does not exists - how can I writeup pause / resume method?

Comment: Try `pause()` instead of `pause ()`

Comment: E:\NodeJS\bas\routes\serial.js:40
            serialPort.pause();
                       ^
TypeError: Object #<SerialPort> has no method 'pause'
    at SerialPort.<anonymous> (E:\NodeJS\bas\routes\serial.js:40:24)
    at SerialPort.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at E:\NodeJS\node_modules\serialport\serialport.js:201:12

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this code on windows? 
The pause() and resume() methods will not work on windows. To avoid this run-time error wrap the call to these functions with an if condition as follows.

```
if (process.platform !== 'win32'){
 serialPort.pause();
}
```

I too got this error and fixed it as above.